# On change event on select button from an View Component

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I have added a view component. It is rendered in shared layout.
I need that the user can change the select option.
On change it must execute the code at controller.

I tried the onchange="myfunction()". My function to do work.

```
@model myapp.Web.Models.Scheduling.ScheduleNavModel
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Id"></label>
        <select asp-for="Id" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.SerialSchedules, "Id", "Name"))" onchange="func()" class="form-control basic-select2"></select>
        <span asp-validation-for="Id" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

</form>

@section scripts {
    <script>
        function func() {
            alert('hi');
        }
    </script>
}
```

Also note that i neeed the onchnage event to execute code in .net core.

```
public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
        {
            var model = new ScheduleNavModel();
            var activeSerialId = Convert.ToInt64(HttpContext.Session.GetString("banner_serial"));

            if (activeSerialId != 0)
            {
              model.SerialSchedules=  _scheduleService.GetBySerial(activeSerialId).Select(x => x.ToModel()).ToList();

            }

            return View(model);
        }

@model Celluloid.Web.Models.Scheduling.ScheduleNavModel
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Id"></label>
        <select asp-for="Id" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.SerialSchedules, "Id", "Name"))" class="form-control basic-select2"></select>
        <span asp-validation-for="Id" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

</form>
```

I expect that the onchange of select, it must render some code in component post. Something like

```
[post]
 public IViewComponentResult Invoke(ScheduleNavModel model)
{
my code here
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Explain "My function to do work.". What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

The js code would not work directly if you add it in view of ViewComponent simply, you need to put it on the parent view.

Besides, ViewComponent does not have a `POST` method, I suggest that you could use ajax to send the form data to an action in another controller.

Below is a demo you could refer to:

ViewComponent view:

```
<form class="form-inline" id="myform">
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Id"></label>
    <select asp-for="Id" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.SerialSchedules, "Id", "Name"))" onchange="func()" class="form-control basic-select2"></select>
    <span asp-validation-for="Id" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>

</form>
```

_Layout.cshtml:

```
<div id="root">
     @await Component.InvokeAsync("NameOfYourComponent")
</div>
<script>
        function func() {
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url: '/Home/TestView',
                data:$('#myform').serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                //do what you would like to do
                //$("#root").html(data.Value);//fill the result view to the div whose id is "root"

            }
            })
        }
 </script>
```

HomeController:

```
[HttpPost]
 public ViewComponentResult TestView(ScheduleNavModel model)
    {
       //your logic
        return ViewComponent("NameOfYourComponent");
       //or return ViewComponent("PriorityList",new { model = model}); if you need to pass some parameters
    }
```

Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.2#perform-synchronous-work